# Find the last blank cell and paste formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newbie and my macro is mix of recorded and written code , hence embarrassed

How Do I fill all blank cells In Column A and B with data below it as there are gaps and i am not able to fill the gaps or cannot think of any other way

```
Sub Macro4offsetselectionfinal()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim lr As Long

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("C:D").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("A:B").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("C1:E5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents


Set sht = Worksheets("00689")
Set StartCell = Range("A7")

'Find Last Row and Column
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Select Range
sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select


Selection.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"
Range("A8:B8").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents


Rows("7:7").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

Range("B7").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(-1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value


Range("A7").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.Offset(-1).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value


  Range("A8").Select

 lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A8:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
  
 Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Formula
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
 Calculate
  Range("A7").Select


 End Sub
```

Using offset doesn't seem to work, can anyone advise

[image]

Thanks,
Jenny

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv8b8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to fill the blanks with the values bellow, here is one version.

```
Sub FillTheBlanks()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A7:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[1]C"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

Before and after results

---

[image]

Comment: Dear Dave , This does work , but if there are more than 1 gap in between , Instead of values , this pastes as "00:00:00" Would you suggest something

Comment: You sample does not show more than 1 gap, can you explain more?

Comment: Hey Dave in Attached Image , Please see highlighted Gaps in Column A and B. Row 10,11,12 / 14,15,16 / 22,23 are empty, those gaps also needs to be filled

Comment: Please see the before an after results

Comment: Ah, what is the formula in the filled cells?

Comment: Hello Dave , Please see question I edited and added a snapshot or what issue I am facing highlighted in Yellow. Formula is all blank cells should be "=R[1]C" which is correct , however I am not able to identify why these times are being entered

Comment: Hey Dave , I identified what was the small issue to be fixed.                            
rng.Value =  rng.Value replaced it with rng.Value = rng.Formula and worked great . You are a superstar for helping me out on this. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: Mark as answer so this thread is answered.

Comment: Hey dave, One last query please, I need to autofill the column till last row. But The last row can be identified in Coumn B as column A is blank Can you help correct the below code

Comment: Sub Macro11()

 Dim AUTO As Long

Columns("A:A").Select
  Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
   Range("A7").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BU"
    AUTO = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
 Range("A8").FormulaR1C1 = "FUJ"
 Range("A8").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B8:B" & AUTO)
  Columns("B:B").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Columns("A:A").Select
   Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Comment: If this is a new question, you can start a new thread. Comments don't show code very well.